# How to confirm that a sample of "random" numbers is representative of larger set using Excel?

Tags: excel, random

Say I have a set of 1 million user IDs, and I pull 10,000 "randomly chosen" IDs from that set using a SQL function such as:

`NewID()`

or

`(ABS(CAST(
(BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) *
RAND()) as int)) % 100) < 1`

Is there any way to use Excel to generate [a bitmap](http://www.random.org/analysis/) or other visual representation to confirm that my number set is indeed "random", or rather, an evenly distributed sample of my larger set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would group the **full** set of 1 million ID's into 10 groups of 100,000 each.  I would then map the 10,000 samples into these groups.

If the draw was truly random, we expect each group would contain **approximately** 1,000 samples.

Comment: This is roughly what I did. In fact, I grouped users in the sample into month bins by signup date, graphed the sample in Excel, and compared the shape of that graph to the shape of the total signup graph. After a bit of tweaking with sample parameters I finally got a graph that very closely resembled the shape of the total signup graph. Not totally scientific, but satisfactory for my purposes. Thanks!